# PyQT / Pandas - Fastest Way To Update Table Widget Data

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Suppose I have a pandas dataframe `df` (or dictionary) such as:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     A     A     0
1     A     B     0
2     C     A     1
3     B     C     0
4     A     E     1
```

And a QTableWidget `tableWidget` with 2 columns:

```
   col1  col2
0     A     A
1     A     B
2     C     A
3     B     C
4     A     E
```

I can update the colour formatting of each row and cell in `tableWidget` based on that's rows `col3` value in the dataframe, by iterating through each QTableWidgetItem. For example to change the background colour for rows where `col3 == 1`, I could do something like this:

```
row_count = len(data)
tableWidget.setRowCount(row_count)

for i in range(row_count):
    row = df.iloc[i]
    cell1 = row['col1']
    cell2 = row['col2']
    cell3 = row['col3']

    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(cell1)
    if cell3 == 1:
        item.setForeground(QtGui.QColor('red'))
        tableWidget.setItem(i, 0, item)

    item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(cell2)
    if cell3 == 1:
        item.setForeground(QtGui.QColor('red'))
        tableWidget.setItem(i, 1, item)
```

However this is very slow. With a dataframe of 2,000 rows, it can take a long time to update the table widget. Is there a faster (better) way of updating the properties of table widget items based on a dataset of values, instead of cycling through each row and cell in a loop? Perhaps by passing a dictionary of formatting values to the TableWidget?

Comment: As you noticed the `QTableWidget` is not suited for large tables. It is recommended to use a `QTableView` and make a subclass of `QAbstractTableModel` to provide an interface between the table view and Pandas Dataframes. See the [Model/View Programming](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) chapter of the Qt Docs. You can also google for _"pandas qabstracttablemodel"_. Many people had the same problem and perhaps you can use their examples or libraries.

Comment: E.g. [this tutorial](https://www.learnpyqt.com/courses/model-views/qtableview-modelviews-numpy-pandas/) seems to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I need. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)